# Is it possible to show trends from an lcov report in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, istanbul, lcov, nyc

I have an lcov report which produces a pretty html report and an lcov.info file.  I want to see on jenkins whether our code coverage is improving or degrading.  Is it possible to do this with an lcov report?  I can do it using cobertura, but for various reasons we need to stick with lcov.  We also need to see statements, branches, functions and lines.

The coverage report is being produced by istanbul/nyc.

Comment: I don't think lcov supports trend analysis. But you can look at www.codecov.io .